# In gae datastore, are all entities in a namespace are stored in same part of distributed network?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Referring to gae docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions

It says: Entity group relationships tell App Engine to store several entities in the same part of the distributed network.

My Questions:

1) Does it hold true in case of namespaces? I mean, in case of multitenant app, the namespace for each tenant dictates the storage of entities belonging to that namespace at same part in distributed network?

2) Is it a nice idea to use an Entity Group  for each tenant and namespace as well?

Answer (score 0):

1) No
2) Not always true. It depends on your goal and access pattern.